# CKEditor 5 and jQuery Validation error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, unobtrusive-validation, ckeditor5

Pretty new to working with CKEditor and I am confused about this jQuery validation error that I have been receiving. My project is C# MVC and utilizing UnobtrusiveJavascript and the Unobtrusive Validate plugin.

I have a text area built via an HtmlHelper:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.BookSummary, new { id = "bookMainInfo" })
```

Here is what I am doing to create the Editor. It replaces the text area when the page is opened:

```
 var theEditor;

// Load CKEditor in place of the information table
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#bookMainInfo'), {
        toolbar: ['heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'undo', 'redo'],
        heading: {
            options: [
                { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Large Heading', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Medium Heading', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Small Heading', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' }
            ]
        }
    })
    .then(editor => {
        theEditor = editor; // Save editor for usage later
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Everything seems to be working okay. I can successfully enter data and submit the form without issue. However, if I have any text entered in the editor and click outside of the editor, the following error is thrown in the console:

```
VM149 jquery.validate.js:1033 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at $.validator.escapeCssMeta (VM149 jquery.validate.js:1033)
at $.validator.errorsFor (VM149 jquery.validate.js:1014)
at $.validator.prepareElement (VM149 jquery.validate.js:692)
at $.validator.element (VM149 jquery.validate.js:475)
at $.validator.onfocusout (VM149 jquery.validate.js:300)
at HTMLDivElement.delegate (VM149 jquery.validate.js:424)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (VM148 jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (VM148 jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
at Object.trigger (VM148 jquery-3.3.1.js:8249)
at Object.simulate (VM148 jquery-3.3.1.js:8318)
```

The error is logged twice, and I can repeatedly generate the error by clicking in and out of the editor with text in it.An empty editor leads to no error. It seems like it is blowing up on this section of jquery.validate.js in specific:

```
    escapeCssMeta: function( string ) {
        return string.replace( /([\\!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1" );
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to supress this error or stop jQuery validation from doing whatever it is trying to do here? It has no impact on me functionally, but it is quite an annoyance.

Comment: how and where are you calling the `.validate()` is validation triggered on blur

Comment: I am in a c# MVC project and am using UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled and jQuery.validate.unobtrusive, so I am not calling validate anywhere in specific. I wonder whether it has to do with CKEditor hiding the text area when the editor is generated?

Comment: can you confirm once by adding this at the top of your page `jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ignore: ":hidden:not(#bookMainInfo),.note-editable.card-block"
});` and check once if it works

Comment: I added that in a <script> tag at the top of my view and the error still occured upon clicking in-and-out of the CKEditor editor.

Comment: Don't you think it's important to mention someplace within your OP that you are using the MVC framework along with the Unobtrusive Validation plugin?  Edited tags.

Comment: Heh, I suppose. I have gotten snipped at for including tags that weren't directly related to my question before (like tagging asp.net in a jQuery question), so I wasn't sure. I will know for next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution that fits my needs. Previously, the #bookMainInfo TextArea was tied to a model property with a [Required] attribute.

The error was occuring because when jQuery validation called escapeCssMeta, it was trying to run validation on the CKEditor editor that was created. The editor does not have an Id or Name, so the "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" message was thrown in the console.

In my case, I was able to remove the [Required] attribute from that field and it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

My error was resolved by added .ignore = ".ck"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('form').each(function() {
       if $(this).data('validator')
          $(this).data('validator').settings.ignore=".ck";
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VM149 jquery.validate.js:1033 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Results because the element that the CKEditor creates for editing has no attribute "name".
One could certainly try to give the CKEditor element a "name" attribute ...

Or you could specifically exclude this element from validation. It is only a tool in the form.  The actual element that is to contain the value from the CKEditor should be validated.

```
$('FORM').validate({
      ignore: ".cke_editable"
});
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore